# How to design a java program using the nextLine method?

Tags: java, binary

Here is what my program should be like:

Java: enter a binary number.

No!

Java: Please enter a binary number.

Well maybe.

JAva:can you lease enter a binary number?

101010

Java: The binary number 101010 is 42 in base 10

However, I cant get it to repeatedly ask for the user input if the input is not valid.
Moreover, I cant use Math.pow.

Here is my codings:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class BinaryToDecimal

  { 
   public static void main(String args[])

  { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");

    String binary = input.nextLine(); 

    int[] powers = new int[16]; 
    int powersIndex = 0; 
    int decimal = 0; 
    boolean isCorrect = true; 


    for(int i = 0; i < powers.length; i++)
        powers[i] = (int) Math.pow(2, i);

    for(int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        if(binary.charAt(i) == '1')
            decimal = decimal + powers[powersIndex]; 

        else if(binary.charAt(i) != '0' & binary.charAt(i) != '1')
        {
       isCorrect = false; 
      System.out.println("Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number");
             input.next();

        }


        powersIndex++;
    } 

    if(isCorrect) 
        System.out.println(binary + " converted to base 10 is: " + decimal);
    else 
        System.out.println("Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number");
                    input.next();

} 
}
```

Problems I'm facing:
Can't use Math.pow
java wont ask for input properly (e.g. When I enter a false input, it ask me to enter a valid input. However, when I enter one, it ignores it. And it doesnt ask until the input is valid.)

If u guys can help me, I will be extremely grateful. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i didn't get your problem.. can you elaborate more??

Comment: My problem is that when I run the program, it works all right, no compiling errors. However, after asking for input, If i enter, for example, 8, it will say "Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number". Now, here comes my problem, if i enter a valid binary number like 101010 it will not convert it to decimal.

Comment: Why not just use the Java library to get the decimal equivalent?

Comment: what do you mean with "Why not just use the Java library to get the decimal equivalent?" Its my homework to design a program. If you mean something else, then my bad, see, Im completely new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is in last else :

```
if(isCorrect) 
    System.out.println(binary + " converted to base 10 is: " + decimal);
else 
    System.out.println("Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number");
                input.next();
```

put braces.

code changes are :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 class BinaryToDecimal
 {

 public static void main(String args[])

 { 
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");

   String binary = input.nextLine(); 

  int[] powers = new int[16]; 
   int powersIndex = 0; 
  int decimal = 0; 
  boolean isCorrect = true; 


   for(int i = 0; i < powers.length; i++)
       powers[i] = (int) Math.pow(2, i);

  for(int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {

   if(binary.charAt(i) == '1')
   {
       decimal = decimal + powers[powersIndex];
       isCorrect = true; 
   }

   else if(binary.charAt(i) != '0' & binary.charAt(i) != '1')
   {
      isCorrect = false;
      System.out.println("Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number");
      binary= input.nextLine();
      i=binary.length();
   }


   powersIndex++;
 } 

 if(isCorrect) 
   System.out.println(binary + " converted to base 10 is: " + decimal);           
  } 
 }
```

Your code is having too many issues check this one as i did some changes.

Comment: Can you please clarify?? Put braces where?? Are the 2 not enough??? thx for answering btw

Comment: ok nevermind. I understand what you mean. However it does not solve my problem when entering a valid binary number after entering a false input. If I enter a valid number, it wil say "Wrong....please...."

Comment: you should assign again **binary=input.next();** as you are doing only **input.next();**

Comment: If I add binary=input.next(); after: else {System.out.println("Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number");
                input.next(); }                                                                                    It will still say wrong input despite entering a correct number.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a method that checks whether the input string is a valid binary literal or not.
2. Check whether it is or not. If not, just display the prompt with the text and do a nextLine again to read further input.
3. Do it again if the user does not enter a valid binary string.
4. If the user now provides a valid one, convert it to decimal.
5. However you have not specified what happens otherwise i.e. if the user does not provide a valid binary literal even in the 3rd attempt.

And if possible, always break down the various components of your program into smaller pieces. Something like this :

http://ideone.com/IbcW3b

The methods that do the job are :

```
private static int convertToBinary(String str) { // returns a decimal representation of the binary string literal }
private static boolean isBinary(String str) { // checks of string is a valid binary number }
```

The code assumes you loop until the user provides a valid input.

Comment: thx a lot penguin!!! But would it be possible to do the same exact thing without using: decimal += Math.pow(2, str.length() - i - 1);                                im not allowed to use Math.pow to convert from binary to decimal. Is there another way???

Comment: Write your own pow method. Should not be too difficult. Initialise the result to 1, loop exponent of times multiplying the argument to the result and finally returning it. Or if you know the input will be fixed in length, just store the power of 2 in an array and use it instead.